# Multiply rows in pandas DataFrame depending on values from c

Tags: python, pandas, database, rows

I would like to get from this:

| nname | eemail | email2 | email3 | email4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stan | stan@example.com | NO | stan1@example.com | NO |
| Danny | danny@example.com | danny1@example.com | danny2@example.com | danny3@example.com |
| Elle | elle@example.com | NO | NO | NO |

To this:

| nname | eemail |
| --- | --- |
| Stan | stan@example.com |
| Stan | stan1@example.com |
| Danny | danny@example.com |
| Danny | danny1@example.com |
| Danny | danny2@example.com |
| Danny | danny3@example.com |
| Elle | elle@example.com |

I know I can create 4 separate DFs with name and email column, then merge all 4 and drop the ones with 'NO' but I feel there might be smarter and more dynamic solution for this.

Comment: Where is your code? What's the problem?

Comment: No code, it's not an error. I'm looking for advise on solving specific problem on how to transform data.

Comment: lots of ways to do this, look at `melt` or `stack` - `df.set_index('nname').stack().to_frame('vals').query('vals != "NO"').reset_index(1,drop=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
result = (
    df.set_index("nname")
    .stack()
    .to_frame("eemail")
    .query("eemail != 'NO'")
    .droplevel(1)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: great minds think alike ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(df.mask(df.eq('NO'))
 .set_index('nname')
 .stack()
 .droplevel(1)
 .reset_index(level=0,name = 'eemail'))
```

Output:

```
   nname              eemail
0   Stan    stan@example.com
1   Stan   stan1@example.com
2  Danny   danny@example.com
3  Danny  danny1@example.com
4  Danny  danny2@example.com
5  Danny  danny3@example.com
6   Elle    elle@example.com
```